# One-Two relation join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

In Table-2 there should be 2 E_NO(55 & 56) for each T_CODE(AB & AC).

I want to join these two tables to display all the T_CODEs and E_NOs. If not available in Table-2 it should display NULL

Table-1

```
T_NO    T_Code
1        AB
1        AC
2        AB
3        AB
3        AC
4        AC
```

Table-2

```
T_NO    T_Code  E_NO
1         AB    55
1         AC    56
2         AB    55
3         AC    55
3         AC    56
3         AB    55
3         AB    56
4         AC    55
```

Result

```
T_NO    T_Code  E_NO
1         AB    55
1       **AB**  **56**
1         AC    56
1       (null)  (null) -> AC 55
2         AB    56
2       **AB**  **55**
3         AC    55
3         AC    56
3         AB    55
3         AB    56
4         AC    55
4       **AC**  **56**
```

Can you guys please help me with the query.

I tried to apply left outer join between table-1 and table-2 but as this is one-two relationship so NULL is not coming for the records which are not available in table-2.

Thanks Matt and Vercelli.

Just one more thing i am trying is to fill the (nulls) with the missing fields. I am trying that with PL-SQL by using some logic but will there be any simple way to do that is my question.

Comment: so T_NO 3 & 4 for Table 1 should be all nulls or not included in the result set?

Comment: What is the relationship between Table_1 and Table_2? For example, for T_NO = 2, Table_1 only has the T_Code = AB, but in Table_2 you still have T_NO = 2 and T_Code = AC. So how is this related to Table_1? Then - can there be duplicates in Table_2, and if so what should happen in the Result? Are you just looking to add rows with null in T_Code and E_NO if the corresponding pairs aren't in Table_2?

Comment: for t_no = 2 and T_Code = AB in table1 only 2 rows match from table2 (where t_code = AB), your result different for t_no = 2 and t_code = AC, may be it must have nulls values ?

Answer (score 1):

Use an auxiliary view (`aux`) and cross join with it

```
with aux as (select 55 as e_no from dual
             union all
             select 56 as e_no from dual)
select t1.T_NO, t2.T_CODE, t2.E_NO
  from table1 t1 cross join aux a
                 left  join table2 t2 on t1.T_NO = t2.T_NO 
                                     and t1.T_CODE = t2.T_CODE 
                                     and a.E_NO = t2.E_NO;
```

Comment: You should use values like this `aux(e_no) as (values (55), (56))` instead of union all

Comment: @Hogan Thanks, I'll look into it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 3 & 4 should return all nulls because there are no matches:

```
WITH cteAllPossibleCombinations  AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT t.T_NO, c2.T_code, c.E_NO
    FROM
       Table1 t
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT 55 as E_NO from dual UNION SELECT 56 from dual) c
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'AB' as T_code from dual UNION SELECT 'AC' from dual) c2
)

SELECT
    c.T_NO
    ,t.T_Code
    ,t.E_NO
FROM
    cteAllPossibleCombinations c
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t
    ON c.T_NO = t.T_NO
    AND c.T_code = t.T_Code
    AND c.E_NO = t.E_NO
```

This answer handles when 'AB' or 'AC' is missing from Table 1 as well.

Edit Per your Comment.  So I am still not clear what you are wanting for your filling in the NULLs.  If you don't want to distinguish between whether it exists or not and just want all possible combinations forget the second select above and just choose.

```
SELECT * FROM cteAllPossibleCombinations
```

If you are wanting to distinguish what matched and didn't some how here is a query that might help you understand that:

```
SELECT
    c.T_NO
    ,COALESCE(t.T_Code,'**' + c.T_Code) AS T_Code
    ,COALESCE(CAST(t.E_NO AS VARCHAR(10)),CAST(c.E_NO AS VARCHAR(10)) + '**') as E_No
    ,CASE WHEN t.T_Code IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'yes' END as Matched
FROM
    cteAllPossibleCombinations c
    LEFT JOIN @Table2 t
    ON c.T_NO = t.T_NO
    AND c.T_code = t.T_Code
    AND c.E_NO = t.E_NO
```

Note both the later pieces of code require the CTE.

Comment: instead of union (or union all) use values statement like this `CROSS JOIN (VALUES (55), (56)) c
 CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('AB'), ('AC')) c2`

Comment: Thanks Matt and Vercelli.

Just one more thing i am trying is to fill the (nulls) with the missing fields. I am trying that with PL-SQL by using some logic but will there be any simple way to do that is my question.

Comment: Simply select * from cteAllPossibleCombinations that will give you 4 rows of combinations for every T_No in Table1

Comment: If you want to distinguish between what has matched and what has not you can COALESCE() or case statements.  So do you want any null to become **Value ** Value?????

Comment: Table-1 having **4**AC**
Table-2 only having **4**AC**55** and 56 is missing
So I want **4**AC**56** to be inserted into table-2
similarly **2**AB**56

Comment: Hi Matt can you please look into this query.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39871099/oracle-selecting-record-with-multiple-column-condition

Comment: @aim_thebest okay I took a look and provided you an alternative answer, but this is the last time I am going to assist until you start showing what you have tried and until you start awarding reputation points by accepting answers and upvoting ones that assist you.  here is an article on how to do that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
SELECT C.E_NO, C.T_CODE, T2.T_NO
FROM (  
   SELECT E_NO.E_NO, T_CODE.T_CODE
   FROM ( VALUES (55), (56) ) AS E_NO(E_NO), 
        ( VALUES ('AB'), ('AC') ) AS T_CODE(T_CODE)
) AS C
LEFT JOIN Table-2 AS T2 ON (C.E_NO, C.T_CODE) = (T2.E_NO, T2.T_CODE)
```

This will give you a T2.T_NO for ones that have values.  If you want to insert the missing ones then just use the query above but instead add `WHERE T2.T_NO is null` and you get the list of "missing" ones.