# Oracle selecting record with multiple column condition

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Here i want to select the `enames` for which the `date` is null for both the events 37 and 49 AND also the enames for which this two events(37,49) are not linked. If `date` for any event is not null then it shouldn't select that `ename`. Here in this example it should fetch only C1,D1,E1 ename. D1 and E1 because does not link to event no 37 and 49

Can anyone please help me out with this.

```
id  ename   event   date
1   A1      37      1-Oct-16
2   A1      49      NULL
3   C1      37      NULL
4   C1      49      NULL
5   D1      50      NULL    
6   E1      30      NULL
```

Just added one more condition. Please

Comment: Can event have values different from 37, 49? If so, what if for an ename there is one row with date not null and event different from 37, 49?

Answer (score 1):

Count relevant rows. If only ename is needed

```
select ename
from mytable
where event in (37,49) and date is null
group by ename
having count(*) = 2
```

**EDIT**

Following new set of conditions

```
select distinct ename
from mytable t1
where not exists ( 
    select 1 
    from mytable t2
    where t2.ename = t1.ename and t2.event in (37,49) and t2.date is not NULL)
    ;
```

Comment: Just added one more condition. Could you please check this once again

Comment: Can new set of conditions be summarized as 'there  exists no row with events(37 or 49) where date is not null ' ?

Answer (score 0):

Changing query assuming that your data does not contains duplicate rows:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM   table_name 
 WHERE  event IN ( 37, 49 ) 
   AND ename NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT( ename ) 
                    FROM   table_name 
                    WHERE  date IS NOT NULL)

 UNION
 SELECT * 
 FROM   table_name 
 WHERE  event NOT IN ( 37, 49 ) 
   AND ename NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT( ename ) 
                    FROM   table_name 
                    WHERE  date IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: I also want the enames which are not linked to event (37 & 39) i.e D1,E1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    ename
FROM
    TableName
GROUP BY
    ename
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN event IN (37,49) AND date IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) = 0
```

The `NOT EXISTS` in @Serg's answer is a great way to go but you can also use ***conditional aggregation*** to do it without a sub query.  When using an aggregation formula such as `COUNT()` or `SUM()` they ignore `Null` values so if the `ELSE` portion of your `CASE` expression is `NULL` it will get ignored and by default `ELSE` is `NULL` if it is not defined.